# How do you setup a schema in dbeaver?

Tags: database, schema, dbeaver

See this image below:
[image]

For some reason I can't see anything in Schemas. But I have tables created that I'm hoping are listed under here and they have schemas. What schema needs to go here or how do I view my tables?

Is there some sort of default schema I need?

I'm using elixir and ecto

Comment: Just to be sure, are you sure that you ran the `mix ecto.migrate` after the `mix ecto.create` ?